# How to get the real file path in android

Tags: android, uri, android-file

I want to get the file path of selected file in android. The files are containing in all format. when i using the below code.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
 File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());
 String filePath = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
 Log.d("LOGTAG", filePath);
```

The Output is getting "/document/image:94518". But i want the output is "/storage/emulated/0/gt.png". How it possible? Please help me?

Comment: Please first tell why you want a file system path. You can use an uri or a content scheme path too for nearly all 'file' operations.

Comment: @greenapps I want to get file path for upload file to server. On this tutorial site http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83 shows the file upload to server. I want to choose the file from phone and get the path to uploadFilePath string in the code given in the tutorial site.

Comment: You should have told instead that you needed a filepath to use a `FileInputStream` like is done in your example with `FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);` .                                    `

Comment: Instead you should open an `InputStream`. Like `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`.

Comment: @greenapps The code i have written Uri uri = data.getData();

            File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());
            InputStream is = null ;
            try {
                is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Log.d("LOGTAG",  is);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  The output is getting android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream@26541d3b. This is not correct output.

Comment: `File myFile = new File(uri.getPath());` ???? Why you have still this code? Remove it!

Comment: `Log.d("LOGTAG", is);` ????? What should be printed there? Impossible statement. Please remove. You got that exception because of this statement i think.

Comment: @greenapps I want to get the is like "/storage/emulated/0/gt.png". i want see it in log. so i use log.d.

Comment: @greenapps I remove unnecessary codes. But the output is not getting correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125923/discussion-between-fazil-tm-and-greenapps).

Comment: You will not get it as you like. Not as a file system path! Dont you understand what i am trying to say?

Comment: @greenapps Ok i understand what you saying. Can u help me how to add progress bar which shows percentage of uploading file in this code. http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83

Comment: Use an AsyncTask. It's makes life easier. And why are you not reporting about using an InputStream instead? Helping you does not make fun in this way.